# Assigning SqlParameter with if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would I go about formatting the below? The value of `@IsCloneOf` is conditional on whether the source record has already been cloned from an "original" record, which can be determined by if the `txt_IsCloneOf` field is null or not.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCloneOf", (If txt_IsCloneOf is null then txt_QuestionID.Text else txt_IsCloneOf.Text end if);
```

This is being used to send values to a SQL stored procedure.

Comment: Is this c# or VB? Looks like a mix of both.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The project is in C#,, I would put the if statement above as being is pseudo code....

Comment: Or simply a regular if else statement with multiple `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, depending on preferred coding styles.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCloneOf", (txt_IsCloneOf == null) ? txt_QuestionID.Text : txt_IsCloneOf.Text);
```

Or

```
if (txt_IsCloneOf == null)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCloneOf", txt_QuestionID.Text);
else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCloneOf", txt_IsCloneOf.Text);
```

Or

```
string isCloneOf = "";

if (txt_IsCloneOf == null)
    isCloneOf = txt_QuestionID.Text;
else
    isCloneOf = txt_IsCloneOf.Text;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCloneOf", isCloneOf);
```

Comment: Have tried all of these methods, and as soon as I implement any "If" then the value stored is 0 (zero) even though that value is not anywhere to be found and used.

Comment: @BrentOliver I would guess that you have an unrelated issue. Did you try putting a break point in the code and seeing if the value of cmd.Parameters is what you expect?

Comment: I think what is happening is that value of txt_IsCloneOf is an empty string '' rather than a null. When I create a record with value then the statement is working. changing the == to evaluate to '' doesn't work however. Have to find out how to say "empty string" in this case.

Comment: changing first line of your second method to: if (txt_IsCloneOf.Text == null || txt_IsCloneOf.Text.Length == 0) took care of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is C# with the tag.

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCloneOf", txt_IsCloneOf == null?txt_QuestionID.Text:txt_IsCloneOf.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txt_IsCloneOf == null ? txt_QuestionID.Text : txt_IsCloneOf.Text
```

Comment: Could you please add some context to your code?

Comment: Have tried this methods, and as soon as I implement then the value stored is 0 (zero) even though that value is not anywhere to be found and used